# Getting ssl error when trying to authenticate user session in google app engine flexible (python flask app)

Tags: app-engine-flexible

Trying to loosely follow this tutorial to setup user authentication in an app that I am creating using GCP and python + flask:
https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/authenticate-users

However, when I try to authenticate the user session by logging in, I get the following error:

> Error while obtaining user profile:
>   {'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Mon, 05 Feb 2018 18:14:29 GMT', 'expires': 'Mon, 05 Feb 2018 18:14:29 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'content-length': '186', 'server': 'GSE', 'status': '403', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}: b'{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}'

FWIW, this error pops up after I select the user account in the google authentication service. I am using python 3.6, running OSX, and the app is being served locally in a python virtual environment. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your `app.yaml`? Also, do you use the `*.appspot.com` url or your own domain name? Are you accessing through `https://`?

Comment: okay I figured it out, it was a dumb mistake. I was using `http://` instead of `https://`. Thanks for the help!